# How to use Google Maps to find a user's location without prompting them to allow or deny the request to use their location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find out the best way to find a user's location without prompting them for access for my website to allow or deny my request to find their location.

An example of this would be going to google.com/maps and it instantly pulls your location without prompting you.

Another example is foursquare.com which finds your location without ever prompting the user for access.

I believe this is strictly IP based, but I'm having an issue with finding the appropriate code for this, and the geolocation is just not doing the trick.

Does anyone have any advice? It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `google.loader.ClientLocation` from the [Google API Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) to get an approximate location without a prompt. However, there's [no guarantee that this will keep working](https://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=586#c6) in the long term.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/X8yTL/2/) that demonstrates it.